# Getting email address which the user has entered

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

Is it possible to get the email address which the user has entered?

I know it's possible to set the email address but there is no method to get one.

Is there any know solution for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation, there is not.

---

The remaining stuff I mention for the sake of answering the question, but **I don't recommend that you do this**, because it's likely to get your app rejected from the store.

It's possible that `MFMailComposeViewController` is set up in such a way that the `toRecipients` is implemented internally as an `@property`.  If that's the case, you can probably do something like:

```
NSArray * recipients = [myMailComposeViewController performSelector:@selector(toRecipients)];
```

If that doesn't work, you could maybe start finding ways to introspect the viewController's `_internal` ivar, or maybe just walk the view hierarchy yourself until you find what you're looking for.

Comment: thx for the answer. thats too bad, because in some situations it would be really great to have this information.

Of course I will not implement it even if get through its likely that they will key you out if post an update or so!

anyway thanks a lot